# Bootstap несколько колонок по центру

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как спозиционировать по центру строки 3 колонки?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите должно быть позиционированние по центру, плюс изменение при уменьшении размеров окна.

вот код части с блоками

```css
.dream__phraze {
  color: white;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 280px;
}
.dream__phraze-pos {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}
.dream__steps {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.dream__item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.dream__mask {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, transparent 100%);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dream__about {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.dream__about-pos {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 12px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.dream__step1 {
  background-image: url("/img/step1.jpg");
  background-position: center;
}
.dream__step2 {
  background-image: url("/img/step2.jpg");
  background-position: center;
}
.dream__step3 {
  background-image: url("/img/step3.jpg");
  background-position: center;
}
.dream__step {
  color: white;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ff4e50;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.dream__step p {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 3px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.dream__caption {
  color: white;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 200px;
}
.dream__caption-pos {
  margin-top: 7px;
}
.dream__topic {
  color: white;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ccc;
}
.dream__topic-pos {
  margin-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="dream col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 ">
                <div class="dream__phraze dream__phraze-pos">How Dreamshare works?</div>
                
                   <div class="row dream__steps">
                   
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 dream__item dream__step1 marginrh20">
                        <div class="dream__mask dream__item"></div>
                        <div class="dream__about dream__about-pos">
                            <div class="dream__step"><p>STEP 1</p></div>
                            <div class="dream__caption dream__caption-pos">Sed leo enim,
condimentum</div>
                            <div class="dream__topic dream__topic-pos">Quisque libero libero, dictum non turpis in, luctus semper lorem. Donec rhoncus a leo sit amet facilisis.</div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 dream__item dream__step2 marginrh20">
                        <div class="dream__mask dream__item"></div>
                        <div class="dream__about dream__about-pos">
                            <div class="dream__step"><p>STEP 2</p></div>
                            <div class="dream__caption dream__caption-pos">Morbi velit risus</div>
                            <div class="dream__topic dream__topic-pos">Nulla venenatis tempor dui in molestie. Nulla quis dictum purus, sit amet porttitor est.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 dream__item dream__step3">
                        <div class="dream__mask dream__item"></div>
                        <div class="dream__about dream__about-pos">
                            <div class="dream__step"><p>STEP 3</p></div>
                            <div class="dream__caption dream__caption-pos">Sed leo enim,
condimentum</div>
                            <div class="dream__topic dream__topic-pos">Quisque libero libero, dictum non turpis in, luctus semper lorem. Donec rhoncus a leo sit amet facilisis.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Класс center-block мне не помог и это тоже:

```
.col-centered{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/x1avxkbb/

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `col-sm-3 col-md-3` достаточно `col-sm-3`. Вместо `col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12` достаточно `col-xs-12`. Вместо `col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12` достаточно `col-xs-12 col-sm-4`. Меньшее условие продолжает выполняться и на более широком экране. В частности, `col-sm-3` и `col-sm-4` действуют [для всех экранов ≥768px](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

Ряд `row` [должен быть](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro) внутри контейнера `container` или `container-fluid`.

Если основной материал растягивается по ширине страницы, то его упаковывают в `container-fluid`, а отцентрированные колонки можно просто завернуть в `container`.

```html
<link href="http://xenglish.ru/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
img {
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/c91d170daa2506dc6a3854ca9af8c49f.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h3 style="text-align: center">How Dreamshare works?</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/86f74ae71496d465bd2039c6d213fdaf.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/b8fe0d89382cee7b53b7443123e083f1.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2877b0a390a2a5e30612276b80bd0633.png" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если три колонки должны нанимать меньше места, чем предлагает штатный `container`, то возможны два варианта:

1. определить для них персональный контейнер (получится вариант, который предложил soledar10 в комментарии к вопросу.)
2. сделать [два вложенных ряда](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting):

```html
<link href="http://xenglish.ru/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
img {
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/c91d170daa2506dc6a3854ca9af8c49f.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
      <h3 style="text-align: center">How Dreamshare works?</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/86f74ae71496d465bd2039c6d213fdaf.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/b8fe0d89382cee7b53b7443123e083f1.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2877b0a390a2a5e30612276b80bd0633.png" alt=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```